# Form twig customize style

Tags: symfony-forms, symfony

i have a problem with customization of my form's style..
I extend the form widget in this normal  way:

```
{{ form_label(form.tipi) }}
{{ form_errors(form.tipi) }}
{{ form_widget(form.tipi) }}
```

But i receive this bad HTML:

```
<div id="requests_tipi" class="form-control scroll-select">
     <input type="checkbox" id="requests_tipi_1" name="requests[tipi][]" value="1" checked="checked">
     <label for="requests_tipi_1">Appartamento</label>
     <input type="checkbox" id="requests_tipi_2" name="requests[tipi][]" value="2" checked="checked">
     <label for="requests_tipi_2">Casa Colonica</label>
     <input type="checkbox" id="requests_tipi_3" name="requests[tipi][]" value="3" checked="checked">
     <label for="requests_tipi_3">Garage</label>
     <input type="checkbox" id="requests_tipi_4" name="requests[tipi][]" value="4">
     <label for="requests_tipi_4">Loft</label>
 </div>
```

I would a list like this:

```
<ul>
   <li><label for="requests_tipi_1">Appartamento</label><input type="checkbox" id="requests_tipi_1" name="requests[tipi][]" value="1" checked="checked"></li>
 ...
</ul>
```

How can i do for customize my Symfony Form???

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

This is how you customize rendering for individual field (`tipi` in your case):

http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/form_customization.html#how-to-customize-an-individual-field

and this is where original formatting is defined (and where you can take an "inspiration" :) :

https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/master/src/Symfony/Bridge/Twig/Resources/views/Form/form_div_layout.html.twig#L45

So, something like this could work (please note i have not tested, it might be needed to be adjusted), just put following code somewhere at the top of the template file:

```
{% form_theme form _self %}

{% block _requests_tipi_widget %}
    <ul {{ block('widget_container_attributes') }}>
    {% for child in form %}
        <li>
        {{ form_label(child, null, {translation_domain: choice_translation_domain}) }}
        {{ form_widget(child) }}
        </li>
    {% endfor %}
    </ul>
{% endblock _requests_tipi_widget %}
```